# Is there any way to get last publsihed date of Contentful entry?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, content-management-system, contentful

I need to get the last published date of entry when it`s published and after unpublishing(in draft state). In published state I can use sys.updatedAt, but I found no ways to get the last published date after unpublishing entry.